# grails 3.2.6 fails to initialise test data "is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i've created a simple grails app with latest v3.2.6.  created a Authors and Book classes in grails-app/domain.

book class in grails-app/domain looks like this ( i have a books class also )

```
package org.softwood

//Author has many books logical model

class Author {

    String name
    Collection books

    //static hasMany = [books:Book]

    static constraints = {
        books nullable:true
    }
}
```

and book domain class for completeness

```
package org.softwood

class Book {

    String title
    Author author

    //static belongsTo = [author:Author]

    static constraints = {
        author nullable:true
    }
}
```

I started app - no errors and tried to use grails console to create a instance of Author and got an error like this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [org.softwood.Author] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
```

so i edited BootStrap.groovy to try and create one at startup  like this.  Why does it not brought up Gorm correctly?

```
import org.softwood.*

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        environments {
            development{
                createDevData()
            }
            test {}
            production {}
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }

    def createDevData() {
        Author a = new Author(name:"will")
        def res = a.save (flush:true, failOnExit:true)
        assert res
        assert Author.get(1).name == "will"
    }
}
```

this errors when i start the app with same message, stack trace as follows

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [org.softwood.Author] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.stateException(GormEnhancer.groovy:387)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findInstanceApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:273)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findInstanceApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:270)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.currentGormInstanceApi(GormEntity.groovy:1326)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.softwood.Author.save(Author.groovy)
    at org.softwood.Author.save(Author.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at test.BootStrap.createDevData(BootStrap.groovy:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at test.BootStrap$_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:10)
    at test.BootStrap$_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(BootStrap.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
    at grails.util.Environment$EnvironmentBlockEvaluator.execute(Environment.java:529)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:510)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:485)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:256)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at test.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: weird gremlin.  Whilst waiting - scrapped as broken and recreated a brand new app again.  recreated the Author/book piece and re ran as integration test - it worked, went to console and type in on interactive console - it worked.  So i've no idea why the previous fresh install didnt work - but clearly broken.  very odd

Comment: Are your domain classes in the same package as your `Application` class? If not you may need to override `packageNames()`

Comment: no graeme they are not - the default Application groovy is in package "package coffeeshopapp" - same as the project.    the domain classes are in "package org.softwood".  as i mentioned doing a gradle clean in intellij seemed to fix again - as does run-app from command line .  how do you mean override "packageNames()" not sure what you mean there

Answer (score -1):

try with this

```
package org.softwood

//Author has many books logical model

class Author {

    String name
    //Collection books

    static hasMany = [books:Book]

    static constraints = {
        books nullable:true    // you may not need this.
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt look like it was grails - when i used run-app on command line it worked fine, and when i tried a gradle clean inside intellij it started to work again.  seemed to be a issue with intellij getting out of step and generation stops working correctly.  running the clean action sort of keeps on top of it - but shouldnt really occur i dont think